# Network boot from HP DL380 G7 using PCI quad port Intel NIC

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, pxe-boot

I have a HP DL380 G7 server with a quad intel expansion card in slot 3.

I can't seem to find anywhere in the iLO/BIOS to tell it to boot from one of these expansion interfaces - is this even possible?

We can turn on the on-board NIC's but our base OS has problems with broadcom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Try F11 for boot options during the POST process.

You may also be able to control this from the Intel BIOS.